# Uri encode everything, including unreserved characters

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8

I need to match my server's signing base for oauth, which percent encodes everything before signing.

Using Uri.encode rather than Urlencoder.encode( base, UTF-8) encodes whitespace and +'s correctly, however I also need the unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") encoded.

Its not too hard to write my own utility for them, but it would be nice if the manual change wasn't necessary. Is there already a utility for this?

Comment: Sadly url encoder will not solve your problem. I had this problem and used a custom utility. Refer to http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96

Comment: So I feared. Ah well! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  To work around a bug in some other componemt?

Comment: Nevermind, just re-read!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out only a few characters needed extra encoding. For the masses:

```
public static String encode(String base){
    String encoded = Uri.encode(base);
    encoded = encoded.replace("(", "%28");
    encoded = encoded.replace(")", "%29");
    encoded = encoded.replace("!", "%21");
    encoded = encoded.replace("\'", "%27");
    encoded = encoded.replace("*", "%2A");

    return encoded;
}
```